# Run a shell file from a github project

Tags: raspberry-pi, github-projects

need some help here.
Im new to linux and all the stuff.
My main problem is to run a specific project from Github(https://puffycv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html)
I'm useing a raspberry pi 4 with raspbain buster on it.
Dont know what i am doing wrog here.
Would be awesome if somebody could test the project on a similar system and gide me trough thx. :D

Comment: Please do provide the error what you're receiving i don't see any problem installing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the main point iam stuck with is when is have to run the ./enumerate_cams.sh file.
if i open it Raspbain is showing me a message to execute the file.
but if i click on that noting happens.
I ve also try to click run in terminal but theres also nothing happend thx.